# What is being said in this audio clip?

Tags: translation, korean-culture, listening

[Here](https://instaud.io/3hS4) is the audio. The translation I have available for now is this one:

- Do you want that kind of money?
- Anyone there?
- There is still a public relations section.
- Give me special reporting policy!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (unintelligible) "뭐 하는 거야 도대체?" "누구누구..." (unintelligible) "특별 보도 지침 내려."

Comment: @Thanks for your help! Could you please provide additional details on the "특별 보도 지침 내려" part?

Comment: Compared to the two similar previous questions I've answered, this one is quite tough actually. xD I can make a guess but may not be a complete answer.

Comment: "특별 보도 지침 내려" I'm not sure for that either... unless I see the context and how it really was spoken. "보도지침" might be said when the government starts to control the news/press in case of national emergencies. "지침(을) 내리다" means the person executes that, "내려" instructing others to do so. i.e. "명령을 하달하다": (often used in military) a kind of command is ordered. "특별" before "보도지침" is redundant. I can tell "특별 보도 지침 내려" is something very unlikely to be heard in reality, what's out of movies or so...

Comment: Yeah you got the right context actually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

뭐 하는 거야 도대체? 특별 보도 지침 내려

What do the medias (or the press) do ? Send a special
broadcasting-guideline to them.

The government controlled the content of broadcasting so that each
press fulfilled but they usually did 8 among 10. Hence "special" may
insist that it must be fulfilled. That is, it contains "strong
force".